# Count actual bytes had been read

Tags: c#, io, byte, streamreader

I am parsing a large file , I like to monitor the process by showing how many bytes that have been read.
The actual code is massive but this parts is how i count.

```
StreamReader sr =  new StreamReader(FilePath);
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null )
        {
            //do parsing jobs

            byteCnt += Convert.ToUInt64( line.Length * sizeof(char) );
        }

 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:n0}", byteCnt) + "  Bytes");
```

The file is 16.9 GB (18,186,477,492 bytes)

but my program counts 34,816,805,164  Bytes

How could this happen? and how to make this number more reasonable?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: what is sizeof(char)? why might this be incorrect for the file (that is not UTF-16 with no surrogate pairs)? note there is approximately a 2x difference. now, check to the ReadLine documentation for where the missing difference is: “the returned string does not contain..”

Comment: A minor difference will arise because `ReadLine` removes the new line and carriage return chars. So you will loose two chars per line. As @user2864740 mentioned you may check the encoding of the file. As an alternative you may try the `Position` property of `sr.BaseStream`. This however may throw depending on the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(char)` is 2 in C# as it uses unicode encoding. If your file is not in unicode, this will not be an accurate measure. You can instead use e.g.

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(line);
// or another example:
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(line);
```

To get the size. You need to pick an appropriate solution depending on what the encoding of your file is.

Comment: As Pretasoc mentioned, “Position” is probably useful, even if it requires underlying stream exposure.